# SQL Server pagination of a result set

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, pagination

I have a very meaty stored procedure in a SQL Server 2000 DB which returns a single resultset. I don't want to (not allowed to) touch the original SP but would like add pagination to the returned records.

Is it possible to wrap this SP with another that takes the returned resultset and only gives me rows X to Y ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create procedure ProcWrap
as

declare @T table (ID int, Name nvarchar(50))

insert into @T
exec ProcToWrap

select *
from @T
where ID < 10
```

**Edit 1**
Don't have SQL Server 2000 to test on and I don't remember if table variables where available then. Here is a procedure using a temp table instead. Added a RowNum identity column that you can use for pagination.

```
create procedure ProcWrap2
as

create table #T (RowNum int identity, ID int, Name nvarchar(50))

insert into #T
exec ProcToWrap

select *
from #T
where RowNum between 10 and 19

drop table #T
```

**Edit 2**
Output from ProcToWrap in this case is columns ID and Name. RowNum is generated automatically.

Comment: Exactly :) that's what I meant

Comment: How would you return the second and subsequent pages of the result set? Or, as Andy asked, the results between rows X and Y.

Comment: select * from 
    (select Row_Number() over (order by userID) as RowIndex, * from @T) as Sub
    Where Sub.RowIndex >= X and Sub.RowIndex < Y

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER()` is not available in SQL Server 2000

Comment: @BvdVen, sorry about stealing your idea :). Just thought that it would be useful to see how you capture the output of a SP.

Answer (score 1):

Get the results from the SP and put them in a temporary table, then you can select X results from that table.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said you will have to put the results of the procedure in a temp table then select the rows you want from that.

<strike>To get a set of rows from your results you need to use the `ROW_NUMER()` function:</strike>

```
SELECT
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS row_number, *
FROM
   Your_Temp_Table
WHERE row_number BETWEEN 11 AND 20 -- For the second page of results with 10 per page.
```

**EDIT:** Just realised you are using SQL Server 2000 which does not have `ROW_NUMBER()`, sorry

**EDIT2:** Since you are storing the results of the query in a temp table you can add an incrementing integer field to that result set and use that as a simulation for the `ROW_NUMBER()` in order to select the row you need.

**EDIT3:** Here's a link to an article discussing [pagination in SQL Server 2000](http://ehockeycoach.net/devgenuity/Articles/SQL/SQL2000Pagination.aspx)